# Как сделать специфическую выборку из базы данных?

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Здраствуйте.

Я столкнулся с такой проблемой, надо сделать выборку из баз данных (mysql), чтобы сначала выводились четыре особых объявления (vip) на каждой странице, а затем объявления с услугой драйв и турбо, а затем простые, т.е. бесплатные (количество драйв, турбо и обычных не ограничено), но есть ограничения на общее количество объявлений на странице (25 шт.).

Постраничная навигация и все остальное у меня есть. Только не знаю, как сделать эту выборку (SELECT) из баз даных.
Есть таблица, в ней 4 столбца (id, text, name и vip). В ней будут храниться данные: 1 - это vip, 2 - это драйв, 3 - это турбо и 4 - это простые объявления. Т.е. бесплатные.
Надо, чтобы все объявления выводились в обратном порядке. Сайт на php.

Если можно, с небольшими коментариями, я самоучка-новичок, буду признателен.

Comment: Я не силен в SQL и делал бы это (по крайней мере, на первых порах) через простой UNION и соответствующие запросы.

Answer (score 1):

> чтоб выводились в соотвествуюшем
> порядке

Используйте в запросе SQL ORDER BY ваше поле.
ORDER BY отсортирует данные (если добавить DESC, то отсортирует в обратном порядке).

Если у вас есть уже запрос, напишите, я вам помогу.

Comment: Я знаю, можно через ORDER BY сделать, но проблема в ином. Вот запрос (SELECTid, text, name, vip
FROM table
WHERE 1
ORDER BY vip='1'DESC (надо, чтобы этот vip=1 выводился по 4 шт. на 1 странице конструктора, limit 4 конкретно к этому vip=1 не получается, выдает ошибку: неправильный запрос), vip='2'DESC, vip='3'DESC, vip='4'DESC, some_date), но общее число объявлений на странице должно быть 25, т.е. надо, чтобы vip=1 выводился по 4 шт. на странице, а остальные по порядку, но общая сумма объявлений на странице 25. Например, как в авито или ам.ру, у них именно так выводится, особено на ам.ру.

Comment: Я думаю, для начала можно сделать разные запросы на разный тип объявлений. Для новичка самое оно!

Comment: Пробовал, так не получится, у меня же постраничная навигация, и для нее надо считать количество объявлений в базе данных, если выводить объявления по раздельности, то постраничная навигация плохо работает, выдает лишние страницы.

Comment: Сделайте два запроса, в одном выводите 4 с vip = 1, потом 21 с vip != 1 и потом при пагинации делайте в первом запросе limit 0,4 и т.д. (с order) и также только с шагом в 21 для второго запроса.